# Ionic Cordova Run Browser give device permissions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

quick question.

I am currently working on an ionic application which I am testing using the comman 'ionic cordova run browser'. This works fine for most things, however when I try to upload an image to the application I get the following message

```
Permission Denied
Sorry, we don't have 
permission to access your 
device's images. Please check 
the settings on your phone 
and try again.
```

While I understand where this message comes from and why it appears, my question is how to I make it think that it has the required permissions when running on the browser?

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Comment: if i understood your question correctly, uploading an image requires cordova plugin which wont work in browser, so you will have to use isplatform('android') before calling upload image function or you can use diagnostic plugin to check whther the device has permission or not